# How to validate enum in DTO so it contains valid values for that enum type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums

I have a DTO:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
public enum MyEnum
{
    E1 = 1,
    E2 = 2 << 0,
    E3 = 2 << 1,
    E4 = 2 << 2,
}
```

When the the request with empty body `{}` is being sent to the method with a signature:
`public async Task<IActionResult> Method([FromBody] MyEnum value)`

the `MyEnum` would default to 0 which is not valid value for that enum. That is why I introduced `[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]` annotation. But still if request looks like this:

`{"MyEnum" : 3}` the `[FromBody]` will just construct `MyDto` with that invalid value of `3`.

**Question:** How I make `[FromBody]` to fail model validation when request contains value that is invalid for `MyEnum`, the only valid values are `E1,E2,E3,E4,1,2,4,8,16`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it:

```
    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
```